# Knex Update Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, knex

Hola amigos estoy tratando de hacer un update con **Knex** pero no estoy mandando mi query bien, alguien podría decirme como debería de escribirla?

```
router.post('/update-info-project',(req,res)=>{
  const {id,mail,phone,url,urlyt} = req.body;


  const queryk =knex('PROJECTS_').where('id', id)
  .update({
    mail: mail,
    phone: phone,
    url: url,
    urlyt: urlyt
  });

  queryk.then(()=>{
    res.render('main');
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

esto es lo que estoy recibiendo como query en mi terminal.

> Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling UPDATE query: update `PROJECTS_` set `mail` = ?, `phone` = ?, `url` = ?, `ulryt` = ? where `id` = ?

Comment: ¿ Como estás recibiendo los parámetros del `request` ? ¿ Desde un formulario ?

Comment: YA listo me faltaba el name de mi id de mi formulario :3

Comment: Deberías [responder tu propia pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), para que sirva a futuros usuarios :-)